# How to check with Jquery if image element exists in DOM based on src attribute?

Tags: jquery, caching, dom, attributes

I have some preview images that can be zoomed.
If user clicks "zoom", the image is cached:

```
var zoomImg = new Image();
      zoomImg.onload = function() {
      image.attr('src', zoomlist[currentFrame]);
   });
```

What I need to know, is how to check if the image is cached or not, to know if I should show the loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if an image is cached by checking it's complete and readystate properties.

```
var zoomImg = new Image();
zoomImg.src = zoomlist[currentFrame];
if (zoomImg.complete || zoomImg.readystate === 4) {
    image.attr('src', zoomlist[currentFrame])
}
else {
    showLoader();
    zoomImg.onload = function() {
        hideLoader();
        image.attr('src', zoomlist[currentFrame]);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use attribute selector like this.

```
if($('img[src="imageSource"]').length){
     //Image is present
}
```

Note: This will find the `img` element in DOM and not cache.

Comment: Ok, it shoul work, because the images are added to DOM after they are cached, but i have tryed this way before to ask here and it didn't work. Will try again now.